# Autocallables - valuation/modelling/booking

Tags: equities, valuation, barrier-options

Recently heard a view on how one should model/book autocallable swaps (in its basic form where there is a series of observation dates on which the product autocalls and there is exposure to the downside). The general consensus around it seems to be that one obviously needs to book series of short digital calls, one for each observation date, and long down-and-in put option. To model/book the autocall feature, one also needs to have an up-and-out barrier, I believe. However, one view is that there needs to be an up-and-out call option booked, which doesn't seem to make much sense. I'd say one needs to book the up-and-out barrier together with the put option and the digitals but not with an extra call option. What are your thoughts?

Comment: You are really just trying to replicate the payoff here, instead modelling these. Usually, AC (any structured product really) is priced with (Stochastic) Local Vol with a Monte Carlo engine. On a BBG terminal you can see this by typing DLIB AC in the command line (provided you have an anywhere license). Problem with your series of digitals and a final down an in is that none of these should exist once it autocalls, and that is not something you can do with a simple series of trades.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I’m actually after booking aspects from valuation control point of view. It’s pretty clear to me how this is modelled and priced. Booking however is a different thing from what I understand.

Comment: Can you expand why booking is a different thing? Sticking to BBG, you can book a DLIB deal directly into your OMS (e.g. TOMS) or MARS. Isn't valuation control just an independent valuation / pricing?

Comment: I believe valuation control look into how you can replicate the payoff through basic building blocks and making sure your positions are fairly valued, may be wrong here tho… Are you saying that in a trading book you'd only book an autocall swap without breaking it down and all the Greeks would be arrived at through Stochastic LV ? Is there a way to squeeze in any up-and-out barrier to model the autocall feature that would knock out all legs if hit ?

Comment: Yes, in trading it will definitely be booked without breaking it down. Most AC are on baskets anyways where any attempt to replicate with simple vanilla options would not work. Many derivatives / structured products cannot be replicated. If they could, there would be no need for any complex modelling. Same applies to TARFs,...